# the second function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just a problem that I have been struggling with. I have created two function which are shown below:

```
function limit_char_normal(textid, limit, infodiv){
    var text = $('#'+textid).val();
    var textlength = text.length;

    if (textlength > limit) {
        alert("Number of characters exceeded!");
        $('#'+textid).val(text.substr(0,limit));
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#' + infodiv).html(''+ (limit - textlength) +'');
        return true;
    }
};

function limit_char_unicode(textid, limit, infodiv){
    var text = $('#'+textid).val();
    var textlength = text.length;

    if (textlength > limit) {
        alert("Number of characters exceeded!");
        $('#'+textid).val(text.substr(0,limit));
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#' + infodiv).html(''+ (limit - textlength) +'');
        return true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#normal").click(function() {
            $('#infodiv').show();
            $('#infodiv2').hide();
            $('#normal_message').val('');
            $('#normal_message').bind('keyup keydown click',function(){
                limit_char_normal('normal_message', 153, 'infodiv');
            });
    });
    $("#unicode").click(function() {
            $('#infodiv2').show();
             $('#infodiv').hide();
            $('#normal_message').val('');
            $('#normal_message').bind('keyup keydown click',function(){
                limit_char_normal('normal_message', 63, 'infodiv2');
            });
    });
});

<input type="radio" name="normal_message" value="normal" id="normal">Normal
<input type="radio" name="normal_message" value="unicode" id="unicode">Unicode

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="normal_message" class="normal_message" id="normal_message" placeholder="Hello Message">
</textarea>

    <p id="infodiv" style="display:none;">153</p>
    <p id="infodiv2" style="display:none;">63</p>
```

When I click on the normal button the `function` works fine. after clicking normal button I click unicode button it works fine as well the character deduct with no problem.

After clicking unicode button and click back to normal it just call function `limit_char_unicode()` and never call the `limit_char_normal()` function.

I have included the jsfiddle for your reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/caocao89/FMNSt/

That would be great if you could help out.

Comment: `limit_char_unicode` is not being called from anywhere within your code (`limit_char_normal` is being called twice - probably a CTRL+C / CTRL + V issue. It happens!)

Comment: As Marlon sais, looks like good time to take some sleep :)

Comment: you are registering a new handler every time a radio is clicked... also since you have keyup and keydown handlers those are firing an insane number of times... I may rewrite it as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6343F/2/

Comment: LOL!! sorry guys. Its my fault. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function named `limit_char_unicode` and it is not called from anywhere.

```
$("#unicode").click(function() {
            $('#infodiv2').show();
             $('#infodiv').hide();
            $('#normal_message').val('');
            $('#normal_message').bind('keyup keydown click',function(){
                limit_char_normal('normal_message', 63, 'infodiv2');
            });
    });
```

Change `limit_char_normal` to `limit_char_unicode` in the above function and try.